# How to scrape a page and then perform a button click to go to next page for scraping using Selenium and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am scraping a web page which has a table with child tr and td tags. I am able to scrape the first page properly. But to go to the next page I need a button click. I need some help in understanding that. I am using Selenium and Beautiful soup to get the page response.

The html for the button tag is as follows:

```
<input type="submit" name="RadGrid1$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$ctl28" value=" " onclick="return false;" title="Next Page" class="rgPageNext">
```

The sample code that I have tried:

```
for i in range(0,14):

  # code for scraping 1 page

   some code here

   btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)

   btn.click()
```

The button click goes to the next page but is not able to scrape info for any of the 2-14 pages. I have tried putting my scraping 1 page code in a for loop and added the button click logic at the end. It scrapes 1st page, performs a button click but doesn't go through to the next page. Instead it loops back to page 1.

Comment: can you share the url?

Answer (score 0):

As to what I can understand, I think you haven't updated the new url to the Beautifulsoup. After the click you take the current url of the new page and then perform scraping. Then only it will scrape the new page otherwise it contains the url of the old page and thus scrapes that page only.